# Is it possibe to upgrade and re-jailbreak (in order to unlock) a 3Gs running on 4.1?

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, unlock

I have a locked 3Gs running 4.1 and it's pretty annoying not be able to install anything on it anymore (most apps nowadays require at least 4.3)

I can not unlock it officially because i bought second hand two years ago and can't reach the person i bought it from :s

So i would like to know if it will be possible to jailbreak it (to be able to unlock it) after upgrading it, or should i just leave it at 4.1 and use the basic functions ?

Modem firmware : 06.15.00

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're a few weeks too late.

There was the Evasi0n jailbreak, which worked on iOS 6.0 - 6.1.2, but iOS 6.1.3 killed it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the IMEI unlock, it costs $5 and you wont need to jailbreak anymore.

Comment: Ability and costs for an IMEI unlock depend on the carrier used, so this answer may or may not be useful to the asker. At least can you please add for which carrier this is an answer and what the procedure is to get the unlock?

Comment: @Licores : Yes please. Could you give more information about this IMEI unlock ? I contacted Apple, they said unlock procedures can be performed by carriers only. The problem is that the carrier don't unlock the phone unless the request is made by the customer who subscribed. So since i can't get in touch with the person who sold me the phone (the subscriber), i'm stuck ...